# Button text wont align correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently cloning a site and in the "enter email" input, the text wont align and sticks to the bottom of the input, and i'd prefer it to be in the middle on the left. How can i fix this? any help appreciated <3

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
:root {
  --primary-text: #111111;
  --secondary-text: #91908f;
  --background: #fffefc;
  --btn-primary: #e16259;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--b);
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}


/* NAV */

header img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 15px 60px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

header nav a,
header nav .vertical-line {
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111111;
  font-weight: 500;
}

header nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Hero Section */

.hero {
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.hero-img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #91908f;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  text-align: left;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #91908f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input::placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form button {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fffefc;
}

form label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

form .btn-primary {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e16259;
  border: 1px solid #af4d46;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Notion</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="https://www.notion.so"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Notion Logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Product</a>
      <a href="#">Download</a>
      <a href="#">Resources</a>
      <a href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a href="#">Careers</a>
      <span class="vertical-line">|</span>
      <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      <a href="#">Log In</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-img">
      <img src="img/hero.webp" alt="Illustration of 3 people using laptop computers on seperate desks with different expressions">
    </div>

    <h1>All-in-one workspace</h1>
    <h4>One tool for your whole team. Write, plan, and get organized.</h4>

    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
      <button class='btn-primary' type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
    <p>For teams & individuals - web, mobile, Mac, Windows</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share your html snippet too

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1190lod

Comment: By html snippet I meant your html code

Comment: i added it to the post in an edit! :) sorry for the bad markdown btw aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove padding of input and adjust by using height and line height

```css
.ip {
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="ip" />
```

Comment: thats worked amazingly :) thank you very much :)))) <3

Answer (score 1):

In `input` selector you can change the `padding-top: 18px` to `padding: 10px`, as below. Then remove that `input::placeholder`.

```css
input {
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #91908f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define height for the **input** class and for **input::placeholder** remove `margin-bottom: 20px;` and set **margin** to **auto** and also add some **left-padding**.

```css
input {
  text-align: left;
  width: 280px;
  height: 40px;/*add height for your input*/
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #91908f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input::placeholder {

    margin: auto;/*set margin to auto*/
    padding-left: 10px;/*add some left-padding*/
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <button class='btn-primary' type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Instead of scratching your head around custom CSS, you can use third party CSS libraries like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/) or [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html) which provide a variety of feature rich CSS components and will eventually reduce your work.